# How to name Pulseaudio USB devices by physical location in USB tree?

Tags: udev, pulseaudio

In this [mailing list post from 2016](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-discuss/2016-November/027205.html), a Pulseaudio user asks how to assign stable names to different USB audio cards which may have identical vendor and serial numbers.

He [posted his solution on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/mpaolino/91c3587045fa8d1a9353b74bf102c83b); it is based on adding a Udev line for each card, based on the card's device path.

I'm trying to modify this solution so that I can add new cards without changing the Udev rules.

I noticed that Udev already gives me two variables that can be used to construct a stable name for the card, if I concatenate them. Here `ID_ID` seems to be the basis for the sink name chosen by Pulseaudio, while `ID_PATH_TAG` contains the port numbers of the USB hubs, which is what I want to be appended to the name:

```
$ (sleep 1; sudo udevadm trigger -s sound -c remove ; \
  sudo udevadm trigger -s sound -c add) &; \
  udevadm monitor --subsystem=sound -p | grep -P 'ID_ID|ID_PATH_TAG'
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_06_00_3-usb-0_3_4_1_1_0
ID_ID=usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00
... (some repeats)
```

How can I create a Udev rule which generates Pulseaudio device names by combining these two variables?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-audio.rules
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="sound", DEVPATH=="/devices/*/usb*/sound/card?", ENV{PULSE_NAME}="$env{ID_ID}.$env{ID_PATH_TAG}"
```

The 99 is important because `ID_PATH_TAG` is being set by an earlier rule (I am not sure which one); using a lower number had caused my original attempt not to work.

Now the sink name contains the `ID_PATH_TAG` which identifies the card by physical location:

```
$ pactl list sinks | grep Name
        Name: alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00.pci-0000_06_00_3-usb-0_2_4_2_1_1_0.analog-stereo
        Name: alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00.pci-0000_06_00_3-usb-0_2_4_2_3_1_0.analog-stereo
```

The location is encoded in the substrings:

```
usb-0_2_4_2_1_1_0
usb-0_2_4_2_3_1_0
```

which apparently means that there is a USB hub plugged into port 2 on my laptop; another hub is plugged into port 4 of this hub; and a third hub into port 2 of the second hub. The audio devices are plugged into ports 1 and 3 of the last hub. I'm not sure about the "-0_" prefix or the "_1_0" suffix.

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 26, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 28, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 27, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
```